# Зависает на попытке заполнить массив для Autocomplete компонента

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, angular

Использую компонент Autocomplete из PrimeNG

```
   <p-autoComplete formControlName="from" [suggestions]="listFrom" (completeMethod)="searchFrom($event)" (onSelect)="selectFrom($event)" [size]="65" placeholder="Откуда"></p-autoComplete>
```

По задумке, при вводе названия города в поле `from` должна выполняться функция `searchFrom($event)`, которая наполняет `listFrom` списком городов.

Но при вводе любых символов в поле, компонент зависает. Хотя при этом, судя по выводу в консоль, `listFrom` уже заполнен. Вероятно проблема где-то в промисах? Использую TS/JS не более трёх месяцев, до этого был на Java.

Объект listFrom:

```
listFrom: string[] = ['a','b','c'];
```

Функция searchFrom:

```
  public searchFrom(event) {
    if (event.query.length > 2) {
      ymaps.geocode(event.query, {results: 5}).then((res) => {
          this.listFrom.length = 0;
          res.geoObjects.each((city) => {
            if (city.properties.get('metaDataProperty.GeocoderMetaData.kind') === 'locality') {
              this.listFrom.push(city.properties.get('name'));
            }
          }).then(console.log(this.listFrom));
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Что значит *Но при вводе любых символов в поле, компонент зависает*. Что значит зависает?

Comment: Попробуйте возвращать промис - `return ymaps.....`

Comment: `then(() => console.log(this.listFrom))`

Comment: @overthesanity И снова здравствуйте :)
Я попробовал так сделать, но теперь команда `() => console.log(this.listFrom)` уже не выполняется. Значит где-то зависает внутри?

Это странно, потому что если внутри блока, до `then` вставить вывод в консоль например, то всё выводится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в коде, судя по документации `ymaps` - `map.geoObjects.each` синхронный и возвращает объект. У вас `then(() => console.log(this.listFrom))` не в том месте, нужно его перенести немного ниже.